# How do I immigrate to Spain with an EU spouse?

Tags: spain, eu-spouses

My husband is a British citizen, but I'm an Iranian citizen. He wants to immigrate to Spain. I want to know whether I should go with him or whether he must go first and find a job? Does it take long?

Comment: What is your residenc?

Comment: See http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3121/can-a-british-citizen-with-a-non-eu-or-non-uk-partner-live-and-work-in-the-eu/3122 http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/how-can-i-get-my-spanish-work-permit-and-residency-through-my-partner-who-is-bri/7052 http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/requirements-to-move-to-eu-country-as-an-eu-citizen-with-an-australian-non-eu and http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/non-eu-spouse-moving-to-spain-with-eu-national-together

Answer (score 1):

Since your husband needs a job to have a right to stay in Spain and sponsor your residence card beyond the first 3/6 months, it would seem easier if he got a job first.

Alternatively, if you have enough savings, you could apply for a residence card as the spouse of an “economically non-active” EU citizen immediately. You could even work yourself on that basis, even if your husband does not have a job yet.

Comment: Can't the wife stay with the husband if he proves his status as an active job seeker?

Comment: @phoog In principle, yes. Job seeking is why I wrote 6 months. After that, it should indeed still be possible if you prove you are still actively and have a good chance of finding a job but I don't know how realistic this is in practice.